# SwiftUI Bindable properties with custom types won't compile

Tags: swiftui

I've created a SwiftUI `Bindable` class with two properties, like

```
public class Clock: BindableObject {

    public let didChange = PassthroughSubject<Clock, Never>()

    public var time: Date = Date() {
        didSet { didChange.send(self) }
    }

    public var useMilitaryTime = false {
        didSet { didChange.send(self) }
    }

}
```

This works exactly as expected. But when I try to add a property with a custom type (either as a struct, a class, or a tuple), it fails to compile:

```
    public var sunriseSunset = (Date(), Date()) {
        didSet { didChange(self) }
    }
```

saying I "Cannot call value of non-function type 'PassthroughSubject'". It also fails the same way if I try

```
    public var sunriseSunset: (Date, Date)? = nil {
        didSet { didChange(self) }
    }
```

The Diagnostics button is unhelpful; it just says that it "Failed to build active schema."

What types can be used as properties of a `Bindable` class?

Comment: Shouldn't you be calling didChange.send(self) instead of  didChange(self)?

Comment: That's it! THANK YOU. If you make this an answer, I can upvote you and mark it correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `didChange(self)` which causes the error. Call `didChange.send(self)` instead.